# How to use Google Sheets to create table of Likert scale results grouped by counts

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, pivot, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I want to take responses to Likert survey items and create a summary table of the counts of each response (text labels: strongly disagree, disagree, neutral, agree, strongly agree).

(sample data set & manually created desired results table available in [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z98qH07-r2Q_Q9IHzKVinLbLPaVbghskU61G0egiWz0/edit#gid=1653562152))

I am only able to do one question at a time with QUERY.

```
=QUERY(likertTable,"select B,count(B) group by B",1)
```

Creating an array of QUERY functions does not always work when one option is not selected for a question, resulting in mismatched row size.

Is there a way to create the desired table with a single QUERY—or other (e.g., VLOOKUP, COUNTIF)—formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(B3:D="",,B2:D2&"×"&B3:D)), "×"), 
 "select Col2,count(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1"))
```

[image]

to sort, add "sort column" manually and pass through another QUERY:

```
=QUERY({ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(B3:D="",,B2:D2&"×"&B3:D)), "×"),
"select Col2,count(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1")),
{"sort";4;2;3;5;1}},
"select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 order by Col5",1)
```

Comment: Thanks! I manually added a sort column and passed it all through another QUERY to get the desired order.

=QUERY({ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(B3:D="",,B2:D2&"×"&B3:D)), "×"), 
    "select Col2,count(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1")),
    {"sort";4;2;3;5;1}},
  "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 order by Col5",1)

Comment: Additional note:
With this method, the questions reorder to alphabetical as well. In the sample, the questions are generic and numbered, so there is no issue. In instances when the column headings are not pre-sorted, be mindful of the resort that occurs.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, based on the order of criteria F3:F7

```
=query(arrayformula(split(flatten(B2:D2&"~"&vlookup(B3:D,{$F$3:$F$7,row($F$3:$F$7)},2,0)),"~")), 
 "select count(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is great. I selected the other option as it didn't require setting the search keys in separate cells. Still, this is definitely a great solution and I will likely alternate between both based on situational needs.

Comment: You are right! What I suggest to make it more flexible according to the number of questions is `=QUERY({ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(B3:D="",,B2:D2&"~"&B3:D)),"~"), "select Col2,count(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1")), {"sort";4;2;3;5;1}}, "select Col"&textjoin(",Col",,sequence(Columns(B2:D2)+1,1,1,1))&" order by Col"&(columns(B2:D2)+2),1)`