# Can a single pivot table in Google Sheets summarize multiple Likert Scale responses?

Tags: google-sheets, pivot, pivot-table, spreadsheet, flatten

I have a data set with multiple columns that contain Likert Scale responses. In the header of each of these columns is a Likert Scale question such as, "How much do you agree with this statement?". The values of each of these columns contain Likert Scale answers that range from: "Strongly Disagree", "Disagree", "Neutral", "Agree", and "Strongly Agree".

I cannot provide a working Google Sheet sample at this time (on my work computer and away from home without access to a personal computer) but I can create sample tables below showing my expected Pivot Table result and a sample data set.

What I would like to do is create a Pivot Table using the data from these Likert Scale questions to analyze the total number of Likert Scale answers for each question. The problem I am facing is that I would like to accomplish this using only one Pivot Table as opposed to creating a Pivot Table for each individual question. So, ideally, I would like a Pivot Table that looks similar to this with the Likert Answers as columns and Likert Questions as rows (or vice-versa) like so:

|  | Strongly Disagree | Disagree | Neutral | Agree | Strongly Agree |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Question 1 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| Question 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| Question 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 4 |

And the data set sample I would like to Pivot looks like this:

| Question 1 | Question 2 | Question 3 | Year Received |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Strongly Disagree | Strongly Disagree | Strongly Agree | 2020 |
| Strongly Disagree | Disagree | Strongly Agree | 2021 |
| Neutral | Strongly Agree | Strongly Agree | 2020 |
| Agree | Strongly Agree | Strongly Agree | 2022 |

Any help/input would be greatly appreciated even if the answer is simply, "Sorry, I do not think that this is possible with a single Pivot Table." which is the conclusion I have drawn.

As far as I am aware, this cannot be done in a single Pivot Table and instead requires an individual Pivot Table to be created for each question (which is not acceptable) or for this table to be created with a formula instead ([which I have already done according to this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71518525/how-to-use-google-sheets-to-create-table-of-likert-scale-results-grouped-by-coun) because I couldn't figure this one out via Pivot Table). I personally rarely, if ever, use Pivot Tables so I could just be missing something basic here and I am curious if any of you Pivot Table heroes out there can solve this one.

EDIT: To clarify, I am hoping to use a Pivot Table because I have Slicers connected to the source data to be able to filter the output table by different criteria such as YEAR.

Comment: just to double-check... you don't want this to be solved by QUERY formula (?)

Comment: That is correct although I should specify the reason why. My end goal is to be able to use Slicers to automatically filter these Likert responses by different criteria on a dashboard. Perhaps my understanding of Slicers is the real issue here. If we can use QUERY() and Slicers then I would be happy with a formula solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try if it works for you with slicers:

```
=INDEX({"", "Strongly Disagree", "Disagree", "Neutral", "Agree", "Strongly Agree"; 
 FLATTEN(A1:C1), QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A2:C&"×"&A1:C1), "×"), 
 "select count(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1", ), 
 "select Col5,Col2,Col3,Col1,Col4 offset 1", )*1})
```

[image]

---

## update:

```
=INDEX({"", "Strongly Disagree", "Disagree", "Neutral", "Agree", "Strongly Agree"; 
 SORT(FLATTEN(A1:C1)), QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT({FLATTEN(A2:C&"×"&A1:C1&"×"&D2:D); 
 {"Strongly Disagree"; "Disagree"; "Neutral"; "Agree"; "Strongly Agree"}&"×'×"&
 IF(G1="", 1, G1)}, "×"), 
 "select count(Col2) where Col3 is not null "&
 IF(G1="",," and Col3 >="&G1)&
 IF(G2="",," and Col3 <="&G2)&
 "group by Col2 pivot Col1", ), 
 "select Col5,Col2,Col3,Col1,Col4 offset 2", )*1})
```

[image]

### [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11Al8poqyKSaxcTSrnfo34ALuyWbr1dMEF9SkwvbRVb8/copy)

Comment: That is a beautiful formula! Thank you so much for taking the time to help. I tried inserting this formula onto my Dashboard just now and the data is summarized perfectly but sadly my Slicer isn't updating this table when filters are applied. This Slicer is attached to the source range that the formula is referencing (ie Columns A:C in your example) and an additional column like YEAR (D). I realize I should have specified that in my original question, and that is my fault, so I have updated the question itself to include that piece of the puzzle.

Comment: @Rob the formula could be easily modified to include sorting and filtering by the year if you wish

Comment: @player0 that is the goal I think I'm looking for. I'm not sure how to accomplish that piece using the Slicer I already have or how to modify your formula to include the filtering by year. Maybe what I need instead of a Slicer is a Dropdown Selection for the user to select "Year" and then use that cell as a reference in the Query() formula to filter by the year column?

Comment: @player0 Im waiting for your adjustment, take the [edited version](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kVTCzaqUM6FSfGUY2KffNaleuwpzW-UhpdMEhn2e_0k/edit?usp=sharing) of your answer and go from there

Comment: @Rob answer updated

Comment: @Osm answer updated

Comment: Rob, I tested a slicer on the source date in a seprate sheet, with @player0's formula that i adjusted in my [ansewer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73297145/19529694), so you dont need to, it doesn't filter the output the formula take all the values persent and hidden by the slicer.

Comment: @Rob there was an issue... updated formula & demo sheet is now fixed

Comment: @player0 thank you so much! However I am receiving an error on my end when plugging this into my real data. With the sample data, it works just fine but I am actually missing some of the Likert Answer possibilities in my real data (for example if none of the columns contain "Strongly Disagree" then the formula throws an error). I am receiving the following error when that happens: "In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows."

Comment: Last observation for future readers, it looks like this formula also relies on the Questions being in ascending order otherwise the results become out of order. If applying this solution to a real data set where the questions are not in ascending order, just add a number in front of each question for the results to be in the correct order.

Comment: @Rob both issues fixed. try now

Comment: @player0 wow! I wasn't expecting a response since I marked this question as resolved but you have, indeed, resolved both of those issues. I appreciate your help more than I can express in words so I'll be sending you something via your donation links shortly. Thank you so much, these solutions have taught me a lot of interesting techniques that I have never considered before.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [*player0*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5632629/player0) [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73296722/19529694)

Use the formula he provided. with some adjustments to the header. but in a new Sheets so when adding a slicer it dosent interfere with the source data.

```
=INDEX({SPLIT(" ,Strongly Disagree,Disagree,Neutral,Agree,Strongly Agree",","); 
 FLATTEN(Sheet1!A1:C1), QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(Sheet1!A2:C&"×"&Sheet1!A1:C1), "×"), 
 "select count(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1", ), 
 "select Col5,Col2,Col3,Col1,Col4 offset 1", )*1})
```

[image]

Comment: This Slicer allows us to filter by the different Likert Answer types but I am actually hoping to slice by Year from the source data. I apologize, I neglected to include that piece initially and updated the question with the missing context about 15 minutes ago (while you were probably working on typing up this response). I appreciate your help and am sorry for not including that crucial element in my initial question.